# How to Hide the Div Before Page Load?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, mouseover

I have an ASP page which consist of a table that is generated with the ASP script. I am now populating the table values from a RSS feed by parsing items in it.

The RSS feeds consist of some Job Vacancies data. The items are: date, JobID, Title, Location, Category, Apply Link.

I have one requirement to make a mouseover to the Job Title. When mouse over to the Job Title, a small popup will display and shows Job Description from the RSS feed. The table is showing all the entries and mouse over is also working perfectly after page fully loads.

The problem is during the page load (before the page fully loads) if a user mouse over the job title in the first row, then the mouse over will shows the first entry, but it affects the last entries. The last entry Job Titles will not displays the description when mouse over. "Firefox error console displays the variable description undefined".

How can I rectify the problem??

Comment: You need to give some more informations, for example the script that make the popup display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved perfectly by setting the below condition

to the mouseover function content.Thanks for the suggestions.
`if(document.readyState=='complete') 
{
//code
}`

Answer (score 2):

One way is to not set the mouse over before the pages loads fully. for that use the body.onload event

rough eg:

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('jt1').onmouseover = showJobDesc;">
    <a id="jt1"> JobTitle </a>
</body>
```

The other way is to set a flag in the body.onload evetn and modify the mouseover code to execute only if that flag is true.

rough eg:

```
<body onload="var myPageLoaded = true;">
    <a onmouseover="if(myPageLoaded==true) showJobDesc();"> JobTitle </a>
</body>
```

Comment: The issue is solved perfectly by setting if(document.readyState=='complete')
{//code} to the mouseover function content.Thanks for the suggestions.